# ASP.NET Chart: How to change font in Chart's Title?

Tags: asp.net, fonts, charts, title

The title of my pie chart is rather small. How do I change the font size or even the typeface of the TITLE of the chart? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code of how you are currently building the chart?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a standalone chart with a custom title:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Font="Times New Roman, 12pt, style=Bold, Italic" Name="Title1" 
            Text="Hello World">
        </asp:Title>
    </Titles>
    <series>
        <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Pie" Name="Series1">
            <Points>
                <asp:DataPoint XValue="5" YValues="5" />
                <asp:DataPoint XValue="4" YValues="4" />
                <asp:DataPoint XValue="3" YValues="3" />
            </Points>
        </asp:Series>
    </series>
    <chartareas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </chartareas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 22):

Steve's answer is correct, alternatively it can be done in C# like this:

```
yourChart.Titles.Add(
    new Title(
        "Gross National Rickrolls", 
        Docking.Top, 
        new Font("Verdana", 8f, FontStyle.Bold), 
        Color.Black
    )
);
```

Documentation on:

- the [Chart.Titles collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.titles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- the [Title Class itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- the [Font Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx) used above (from the System.Drawing)

Comment: I was at a loss of how to do this in C#, so this really solved the issue for me, but the +1 is mostly for the Example title you used :-)